# C# Error 1 A local variable named 'userin' is already defined in this scope

Tags: c#

Error   1   A local variable named 'userin' is already defined in this scope

```
    myclass.fillAccounts();

        //int i = 0;
        //while (i != 1)

        string userin = null;

        while (userin !="x") 
        {
            //use the following menu:            
            Console.WriteLine("*****************************************");
            Console.WriteLine("enter an a or A to search account numbers");
            Console.WriteLine("enter a b or B to average the accounts");
            Console.WriteLine("enter an x or X to exit program");
            Console.WriteLine("*****************************************");
            Console.Write("Enter option-->");
            userin = Console.ReadLine();
            if (userin == "a" || userin == "A")
            {
                myclass.searchAccounts();
            }
            else if (userin == "b" || userin == "B")
            {
                myclass.averageAccounts();
            }
            else if (userin == "x" || userin == "X")
            {
              break;
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You entered an invalid option");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did all your code make it into the question?

Comment: What comes before this code snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere else in that method in the code you did not provide, you already have a line of code that says something like this:

```
string userin;
```

You have later said:

```
string userin = null;
```

Which is attempting to redefine a local variable. Get rid of the first variable declaration and you should be good to go for this issue. (You want to keep the declaration with the initial value, because you need that variable initialized by the time the `while` condition is evaluated.)

Comment: I have been looking at this all night I made a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If this is all the code from the method then likely you have a field on the class named userin.  Is this a partial class?  Is it a WPF/Winforms/Webforms class?  Perhaps you have a control named userin?

Comment: A class-level field really wouldn't present an issue, as the local would hide the class member without a `this` identifier (assuming instance method) or the class name identifier (if static). He has a competing local.